# how to interpret "grep -Rl jdk1.7.0_80 . | xargs sed -i s,jdk17.0_80,weblogic"?

Tags: sed, grep

I have just installed Oracle weblogic on rhel server. Installation went successfully however the install guide given to me to run below command without explanation. I would like to know what I am getting into.

```
grep -Rl jdk1.7.0_80 . | xargs sed -i s,jdk17.0_80,weblogic,
```

- jdk1.7.0_70 is installed at /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80
- weblogic is installed at /some/path/name and the install guide asks me to run the command within /some/path/name.

Comment: This is supposed to change the string `jdk17.0_80` to `weblogic` in all files that contain it (under the current dir). It has nothing to do with the actual executables. The trailing comma is missing from the `sed` command though (and most likely, there should be a `g` too).

Comment: If you want to see what it does (sort of dry-run) simply remove the `-i` and run  it.

Comment: yes, you are right trailing comma is missing. I added it back to the original post. Thank you for your explanation. i feel better what I am about to do.

Comment: got it! will try it!

Comment: Simplest way to learn about it is to put ````echo```` before the sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking down what [don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) stated:

1. `grep -Rl jdk1.7.0_80 .` will search the current location (`.`), recursively (`-R`), for `jdk1.7.0_80`, and return the name of each file with a match (`-l`).
2. `|` will "pipe" the output to the next command, `xargs`.
3. `xargs` will build and execute commands from standard input (e.g. the pipe). In this case, it will build a series of `sed` commands from the file list returned by `grep`.
4. `sed -i s,jdk17.0_80,weblogic, <filename>` will edit each file in place (`-i`) and substitute (`s`) according to the regular expression that follows. Note that the sed s-command documentation uses the typical regex delimiter of `/` but states that any character, such as `,` may be used.

Comment: it is very clear to me what is happening! Thank you!